# MVC 4 - Should I use a partial view in a home controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, partial-views

I am in the process of learning MVC4, trying to understand best practices for controllers separation. By now, I've learned that it's good to have a controller for each logical unit of your site.

So for example, if I have a site for restaurant reviews which holds reviews, restaurants and reviewers, I will add three matching controllers. Each controller knows how to create a list view of the entities (and probably some more functions).

The home controller currently knows how to create views for : "About", "Contact Us" ...
I want it's main Index action to show top 10 reviewers/reviews/restaurants. Those "top 10" lists have a different look than the corresponding lists in the dedicated controllers.

So for reviews, will it be a good practice to create a partial view in folder
Views => Reviews => _ReviewsTopTen.cshtml ?

(This view is used only in the Index action of the home contoller)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would look at your markup and decide whether it is sufficient to require splitting out into a partial view in the first place.  If not then it is perfectly fine to keep in the view itself.  No point over abstracting things for the sake of it.

If you do need a partial view and it is only to be used within the Home controller then the correct place for that would be Views > Reviews > _ReviewsTopTen.cshtml.

If however the markup within the partial is the same as another section of your site and it is only the css styling that is different, then you should create a partial view in Views > Shared so that it can be used in several controller views.

Answer (score 0):

i think best practices for controllers logic separation is use `@Html.Action()` method in your home view for each logical unit u need to display. So for example if you need to show 10 Reviews in home controller view it would be something like`@Html.Action("TopTenReviews", "Reviews(<-controller name)")`